# android: what is the value of intent when nothing is put on?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a dialog pop up in the middle of the program and the user has to

specify between two options then click confirm

problem arises when the user selects nothing then click the confirm button

so i need a way to notice that user hasnt selected anything

and add that check inside confrim button's click listener

im thinking of

```
....
.setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

   if (intent == null)
     { //do nothing or tell the user to select on something }
   else
     { getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, i);}}
```

of course intent == null doesnt work, so what code should I use?

Comment: isn't that "nil" instead of "null" or am I wrong ?

Comment: How are the two options defined?  Are they checkboxes or some other control?

Comment: they are textboxes and when they are clicked intent gets defined

Comment: Why don't you post more of the related code so we can understand better what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Intent with action name without extras will not be null. if you want to check extras is there with intent then try the following code

```
if (intent.getExtras() == null) {
  // do something if there is not extras.
} else {

}
```